# App stuck on runModalForWindow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to display a modal dialog on top of my app but it's blocking my main app window when it closes. Here's my code:

```
TutorialWindowController* pTutorialController = [[TutorialWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"TutorialWindow"];
NSWindow* pTutorialWindow = [pTutorialController window];
DDLogInfo(@"Tutorial window opening...");
[NSApp runModalForWindow: pTutorialWindow];
DDLogInfo(@"Tutorial window closed!"); // CODE NEVER GETS HERE
[NSApp endSheet: pTutorialWindow];
[pTutorialWindow orderOut: self];
```

In the modal dialog, my Close button runs this:

```
- (IBAction)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [NSApp stopModal];
}
```

The modal dialog displays fine. However, when I click the Close button, the dialog disappears and my app's main window isn't responsive. I hear the bonk every time I try clicking. I'm pretty sure this is because the code never continues after runModalForWindow. Same thing happens if I close the modal dialo using the red X.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After ordering out the tutorial window, try doing a

```
  [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

on your main window.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `[pTutorialWindow orderOut:nil]` first.

Comment: call first? where. Please add some more details

Comment: Just before `[NSApp endSheet:pTutorialWindow];`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the closeButtonPressed handler. But try adding to the delegate:

```
- (void) windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // ...
    // In there, you should verify that you are calling:
    [NSApp stopModal]
}
```

Adding the stopModal call solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the Window delegate in the Interface Editor's Connection Inspector is connected to the File's Owner.

I had several modal dialogues working correctly except for one, and the missing connection was the only difference.  Making the connection fixed the problem.

Comment: Didn't work for me